# how add a sidebar to navbar with materialize?

Tags: javascript, css, html, materialize

This is what I want: when I click the username (in **header**), show the **sidebar**. This only works out of the **nav** label and I must use **a** label. In a button not works.

### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/icon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="side-setting" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">ver perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">editar perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout/">cerrar sesion</a></li>
    </ul>

    <nav class="teal" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container-fluid">
            <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grupos</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-activates="side-setting" class="navbar-collapse">username</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <a href="#" data-activates="side-setting" class="button-collapse">here</a>
    <button class="btn" data-activates="side-setting" class="button-coll">sidenav</button>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### init.js code

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
        $('.parallax').parallax();

    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

how I add this sidebar? I want this float to the right when I click in a button or username that is positioned in header (nav)